# Is it possible to integrate Instagram OAuth in private API?

Tags: api, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

I'm wondering if it's possible to use a private Instagram API (like [ping](https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api), [mgp25](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API) or [instagram-private-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-private-api)) with the offical OAuth Instagram authentication, so without using unsecure login information forms.

So essentially, I'm looking for some integration that let me use the access token instead of username and password to call the private endpoints.

I'm asking because Instagram has deprecated most of the official enpoints, but some app (like [Reports+](https://reportsapp.org/)), are still using the OAuth login to provide extra functionalities through some private API, and I really don't know how they are doing this!

Could anyone help me in this?